# Problem with download link url AWS S3 (contain excel file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a problem with download link url from `AWS S3`

I hit my backend API and then as a result i got response which contain AWS S3 url to download file (Contains Excel file). Take a look at my code :

```
const onDownload = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await api({
        method: "get",
        url: `cms/user/wishlist?customStart=${startDate.toLocaleDateString(
          "en-CA"
        )}&customEnd=${endDate.toLocaleDateString("en-CA")}&isDownload=true`,
      })
      console.log(result.data);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      const fileName = `comeby-list-user-wishlist.xlsx`;
      link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([result.data.link_download])
      );
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error download list user wishlist");
    }
  };
```

and my result.data is like this :

```
{link_download: 'https://dashboard-excel.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Excel-15052023.xlsx'}
```

If i copy the url link in address bar, it will automatically download the Excel file, but i need to format the name of file by default as `comeby-list-user-wishlist.xlsx`. The problem is that the file is successfully downloaded but I get this error when i open it:

Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scSVW.png)

Is there something wrong in my function? Please let me know if something's wrong and sorry for my bad english. I'm using react-js and axios btw. Thank you

Comment: If you're going to use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) then you need to pass it the bytes of the downloaded file, not a link to the downloaded file afaik.